# Why doesn't FullSimplify drop the Re function from an expression known to be real?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex, assumptions

For some reason Mathematica does not properly simplify this expression:

```
In[7]:= FullSimplify[ArcTan[-Re[x + z], y], (x | y | z) \[Element] Reals]
Out[7]= ArcTan[-Re[x + z], y]
```

Obviously, if `x` and `z` are real, then so is `x+z`, so `Re[x + z]` should be replaced by `x + z`.
Strangely enough, dropping any small part of the input fixes the problem, here are some examples.
No minus sign:

```
In[8]:= FullSimplify[ ArcTan[Re[x + z], y], (x | y | z) \[Element] Reals]
Out[8]= ArcTan[x + z, y]
```

No `z`:

```
In[9]:= FullSimplify[ArcTan[-Re[x], y], (x | y | z) \[Element] Reals]
Out[9]= ArcTan[-x, y]
```

No `y`:

```
In[10]:= FullSimplify[ArcTan[-Re[x + z]], (x | y | z) \[Element] Reals]
Out[10]= -ArcTan[x + z]
```

Of course I can just drop the `Re` function manually, but this is just a small fragment of the actual expression I'm trying to simplify, and I would like to avoid going though the whole expression looking for this specific pattern.
Anyone knows how to fix this? Is this a bug or what? (I'm using version 8.0.4.0)

Comment: It also doesn't work with `FullSimplify[{-Re[x + z], 0}, (x|z) \[Element] Reals]`.

Comment: `Simplify[Re[x + z], Assumptions -> {x \[Element] Reals, y \[Element] Reals, z \[Element] Reals}]` does give x+z so it has to do with ArcTan

Comment: `ComplexExpand` doesn't drop it either.

Comment: FullSimplify[ArcTan[-(y/Re[x + z])], 
 Assumptions -> {x + z > 0, y \[Element] Reals}] also works.

Comment: @celtschk - you're right, the `ArcTan` is redundant

Comment: @b.gatessucks - yes that works, but you loose the functionality of the two-argument `ArcTan`, which takes into account which quadrant the point (x+z,y) is in.

Comment: @b.gatessucks: Note that my example has *no* `ArcTan` and yet is *not* simplified. This clearly shows that the problem is not specifically with `ArcTan` but with any expression with two (and probably also more) arguments. It doesn't matter if the head of the expression is `ArcTan`, `f` or `List`. As soon as there are two arguments, `-Re[x+z]` is no longer simplified (also note that I completely removed `y` in my example).

Comment: @celtschk I think the simplification does occur if one lists all the assumptions; I agree it does not if one uses "|" to specify the assumptions.

Comment: @b.gatessucks: I just tried `FullSimplify[{-Re[x + z], 0}, x \[Element] Reals && z \[Element] Reals]` and it doesn't get simplified either. To achieve maximal separation of assumptions, I even tried `Assuming[x \[Element] Reals,Assuming[z \[Element] Reals,FullSimplify[{-Re[x + z], 0}]]]`, again no simplification happens.

Comment: I suspect the `ArcTan` problem arises due to the possibility of an indeterminate answer: `Re[x/z]` won't simplify further, either.  Regardless, it is instructive to examine lots of simple cases at once, as in `ClearAll[x, y, z];
FullSimplify[#, (x | z) \[Element] Reals ] & /@ { 
  Re[x + z], - 
   Re[x + z], -y Re[x + z], -Re[x - z], -Re[x z], Re[x / z], -Re[
    x z^2], Re[
   ArcTan[x, z]], -Re[-Max[x, z]], -Re[Exp[x + z]], -Re[
    Log[Exp[x + z]]], -Re[Exp[x]/Exp[z]]}`

Comment: @whuber It doesn't seem to be `ArcTan` problem at all. If you set `ArcTan[-1.0 Re[x + z], y]` instead of `ArcTan[- Re[x + z], y]` it works fine. See my answer for a more throughout discussion.

Comment: @Artes I did read your reply before posting.  Did you try out my suggestion?  It shows there is a problem with `ArcTan` even in the absence of any multiplications by -1.  Incidentally, `ArcTan[-1.0 Re[x + z], y]` does *not* correctly simplify for me: I'm still running version 8.0.0.0.  Maybe we're witnessing some version differences?

Comment: @whuber It seems the case here, although it is strange enough, because I'm using ver. `8.0.4` but I checked the results as well as in ver. `7.0.1` and haven't detected any problems with `ArcTan`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem is due to Mathematica thinking that the version with the `Re[]` is actually simpler. This is because the default complexity function is more or less `LeafCount[]`, and

```
In[332]:= ArcTan[-Re[x+z],y]//FullForm
Out[332]//FullForm= ArcTan[Times[-1,Re[Plus[x,z]]],y]
```

whereas

```
In[334]:= ArcTan[-x-z,y]//FullForm
Out[334]//FullForm= ArcTan[Plus[Times[-1,x],Times[-1,z]],y]
```

Here is a function that counts leaves without penalizing negation:

```
In[382]:= f3[e_]:=(LeafCount[e]-2Count[e,Times[-1,_],{0,Infinity}])
{LeafCount[x],LeafCount[-x],f3[x],f3[-x]}
Out[383]= {1,3,1,1}
```

If you tell mathematica to simplify using this complexity function then you get the expected result:

```
FullSimplify[ArcTan[-Re[x+z],y],(x|y|z)\[Element]Reals,ComplexityFunction->f3]
```

> Out[375]= ArcTan[-x-z,y]

Comment: This is exactly the answer I got from Wolfram support. It's pretty amazing that this quirky behavior actually has an explanation. I think that in the root of this is the fact the Mathematica can't have an expression of the form `-(x+y)` without automatically expanding it. Having some function in the middle like `-Re[x+y]` allows multiplying by `-1` only once.

Comment: It is a nice example showing that the concept of simplifying something is actually pretty complicated.

Answer (score 7):

I think this is a bug.

Close enough expressions yield  better results, e.g.

```
FullSimplify[ 
             ArcTan[ -# Re[x + z], y], (x | y | z) \[Element] Reals
            ] ===
             ArcTan[ -# (x + z), y] & /@
  { 1.0,   1, Sqrt[1.], Exp[0.], 1 - 0., 2, a}
```

> ```
> {True, False, True, True, True, True, True}
> ```

The problem seems to be specific for a factor `-1` before `Re[x + z]`, other factors appear to give what we would expect. If there is `ArcTan[-a Re[x + z], y]` in the expression it works well. It should be noted that the same issue comes with `Simplify` and that the problem has nothing to do with `ArcTan`,  because :

```
(FullSimplify[-# Re[x + z], (x | y | z) \[Element] Reals]
         ===  -# (x + z)) & /@ 
  { 1.0,  1, Sqrt[1.], Exp[0.], 1 - 0., 2, a}
```

> ```
> {True, False, True, True, True, True, True}
> ```

To fix the problem you could use e.g. `Refine` instead of `FullSimplify`,

```
Refine[ ArcTan[ -Re[x + z], y], (x | y | z) \[Element] Reals]
```

> ```
> ArcTan[-x - z, y]
> ```

**Edit**

Another way to deal with similar expressions wolud be hiding a `minus` sign into 
  `Re`, e.g.

`Re[-(x + z)]` instead of `-Re[x + z]`.

Sometimes a more flexible way would be some kind of replacement, i.e. setting 
`ArcTan[-a  Re[x + z], y]]` wherever in `expr` one finds `ArcTan[- Re[x + z], y]]` and then `expr /. a->1`

```
FullSimplify[ ArcTan[ -a Re[x + z], y], (x | y | z) \[Element] Reals] /. a -> 1
FullSimplify[ArcTan[ Re[-(x + z)], y], (x | y | z) \[Element] Reals]
```

> ```
> ArcTan[-x - z, y]
> ArcTan[-x - z, y]
> ```

Comment: I submitted a bug report with Wolfram support, I will update here if there are news.

Comment: I got a response - see @Lev-Bishop's answer