# FullSimplify giving unexpected result

Tags: simplifying-expressions

When I perform a `FullSimplify` on the list
$$
\left\{-\sqrt{5-2 \sqrt{6}},\sqrt{5-2 \sqrt{6}},-\sqrt{5+2
   \sqrt{6}},\sqrt{5+2 \sqrt{6}}\right\}
$$
I get
$$
\left\{\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3},-\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3},-\sqrt{5+2
   \sqrt{6}},\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}\right\}
$$
Note the third expression did not get simplified to $-\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}$ for some reason. Is this a bug or does Mathematica's complexity function genuinely consider $-\sqrt{5+2\sqrt{6}}$ simpler than $-\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}$?

My expression in input form:

```
{-Sqrt[5 - 2*Sqrt[6]], Sqrt[5 - 2*Sqrt[6]], -Sqrt[5 + 2*Sqrt[6]], Sqrt[5 + 2*Sqrt[6]]} // 
  FullSimplify
```

Comment: Related link：http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15920/how-do-i-simplify-expressions-with-square-roots

Comment: Also related: [(4135)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4135), [(23441)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23441), [(39351)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39351)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need a custom `ComplexityFunction`. Essentially `Simplify` tries to minimize the `SimplifyCount` of the expression. This function is defined [here](http://wolfram.com/xid/0bnhtcjqmulci-hk3jzl).

In your case the original expression is deemed simpler:

```
SimplifyCount[-Sqrt[5 + 2*Sqrt[6]]]

(* 16 *)

SimplifyCount[-Sqrt[2] - Sqrt[3]]

(* 17 *)
```

Here's a custom `ComplexityFunction`:

```
FullSimplify[-Sqrt[5 + 2*Sqrt[6]], ComplexityFunction -> (SimplifyCount[#] + 
 100 Count[#, Power[v_, _] /; ! FreeQ[v, Power]] &)]

(* -Sqrt[2] - Sqrt[3] *)
```

Comment: `SimplifyCount` is also found in the ``Simplify` `` context: ``Simplify`SimplifyCount``.

Answer (score 2):

For me this whole thing remains rather mysterious:

```
FullSimplify[-Sqrt[5 + 2*Sqrt[6]], ComplexityFunction -> LeafCount]
```

gives the desired expansion

[image]

despite the fact that `SimplifyCount` as per Chip Hurst's link

```
SimplifyCount[-Sqrt[2] - Sqrt[3]]
```

> 17

shows a higher leaf-count than

```
SimplifyCount[-Sqrt[5 + 2 Sqrt[6]]]
```

> 16

**On the other hand**

```
FullSimplify[Sqrt[5 - 2 Sqrt[6]], ComplexityFunction -> LeafCount]
```

[image]

where both forms have equal leaf-count doesn't expand

```
SimplifyCount[Sqrt[5 - 2 Sqrt[6]]] == SimplifyCount[-Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[3]] == 14
```

> True

Comment: LeafCount & SimplifyCount are not equivalent:

SimplifyCount[p_] :=
 Which[Head[p] === Symbol, 1,
  IntegerQ[p], 
  If[p == 0, 1, Floor[N[Log[2, Abs[p]]/Log[2, 10]]] + If[p > 0, 1, 2]],
  Head[p] === Rational, 
  SimplifyCount[Numerator[p]] + SimplifyCount[Denominator[p]] + 1,
  Head[p] === Complex, SimplifyCount[Re[p]] + SimplifyCount[Im[p]] + 1, 
  NumberQ[p], 2,
  True, SimplifyCount[Head[p]] + 
   If[Length[p] == 0, 0, Plus @@ (SimplifyCount /@ (List @@ p))]]

#[-Sqrt[5 + 2*Sqrt[6]]] & /@ {LeafCount, SimplifyCount}

{15, 16}

#[-Sqrt[2] - Sqrt[3]] & /@ {LeafCount, SimplifyCount}

{15, 17}

Comment: This is not an answer, but an extended comment. I would agree that it is too long to post any other way, but I think it needs a statement at the beginning warning readers looking for an answer, that it is only an extended comment.

Comment: It seems me that @eldo rises here one of the Mma mysteries. I also have several times met situations when `Simplify` or `FullSimplify` with worked "in the direction" opposite to that indicated by the `ComplexityFunction`.